# How am I connecting to Ubuntu 14.04 server via FTP? No vsftpd or proftpd installed

Tags: networking, server, ssh, ftp

My computer was stolen about 6 months ago. 
I have just gotten a new computer, and setting up connecting with my VPS, that runs Ubuntu server 14.04. Its been awhile so I cant remember, and also I didnt have my old pc for long before it was stolen.

I can connect to it via secure FTP using a key (PKK).
I documented how I set up the server but theres nothing for FTP.

When I search for how to FTP to ubuntu, most times people recommend installing vsftpd or sometimes proftpd. Neither are installed on my server.

I see I have following installed on the server:

```
i   ftp                             - classical file transfer client
```

After googling I cant tell if it is installed by default or I installed it because it is such a generic name ('ftp').

I was wondering how am I connecting to my server? What did I do to set it up?
What if I need to add new uses how do I do that?

Thanks for any recommendations on how I can look into it.

Kind Regards

Comment: Please clarify how exactly you are connecting to it via "ftp" in your question (ie, what client application you are using). FTP and SFTP are not the same thing. The latter is a feature of SSH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ftp` package is [just a client](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ftp). You are connecting using `sftp` if you are using keys, which is part of `openssh-server`.

Creating new unix user, you will allow this user to log in also over `sftp`, if you have default configuration.

Comment: That is it, I see openssh-server is installed. Thank you!

Comment: if this answer solved your issue, please select this as an answer.